# Use href of a link tag (<a>) to identify the operation

Tags: jquery, seo

I style  tag as a button and use it in place of `<button>` or `<input submit>` tags.

To identify an operation, I use href attribute, e.g.:

```
<a href='update'>Update</a>
<a href='delete'>Delete</a>
```

and then using jQuery:
    $('a[href="update"]').click(function() { ... });

it works well. I also use href attribute as a value for "operation" parameter, when given link acts as a submit button on a form.

Now the **question** - will search engines penalize me for having blind links? (I think so).
How do I work around? use `#update` instead?
I can't use `id` attribute, since there might be more than one button performing same operation.

Note: click handler can be wired using class, which is rather convenient. So I would rather not use `id` to wire multiple buttons to the same handler.

```
<!-- inside a form -->
<a href='update' class='submit-button'>Update</a>

<!-- inside $(function() { .. });
$('a.submit-button').click(function() {
    // 1. get href of the clicked link : href = $(this).attr('href');
    // 2. add <input hidden> to the form: <input type='hidden' name='operation' value='<href>'/>
    // 3. submit form : $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Interesting article about ajax pages and crawling (same premise, JS taking over "traditional" browser events): http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use another attribute and keep things simple?

```
<a href="#" data-action="update">Update</a>
<a href="#" data-action="delete">Delete</a>
```

You can use anything you want, though using `data-` conforms to HTML5 standards. But nonstandard tags will just be ignored by every browser anyway, there's no downside other than failing validation.

Comment: should I use `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`?

Comment: I like your suggestions. But I feel uneasy about using HTML5 in HTML4 world. Besides, failing validation reduces one's epeen value.

Comment: For your first comment: I think the general consensus is "#" - the question comes up from time to time. It doesn't really matter - # is more concise, at a minimum. For your 2nd, well, epeen is a consideration. At the same time, HTML/Javascript/The Entire WWW is one giant hack, cobbled together over 20 years. Many of its "standards" began as hacks. It's a miracle it works as well as it does. If you're afraid to throw a custom attribute in once in a while, well, you probably also believe in graceful degradation and supporting LYNX. Se we'd have little to discuss at that point.

Comment: Sorry I mean "progressive enhancement" not "graceful degradation" :) Not exactly the same, but generally, I mean the idea that your web site is gonna work in Netscape 2.0.

Comment: I like data-action, but i think it may freak out other engineers that come in behind me who arent quite used to this construct yet.  href="#" is how I roll.

Comment: @devildog, well, that is a good reason to use classes instead. There's nothing wrong with that approach either, but I find custom attributes define intent more clearly than adding classes that act as "marker interfaces." I think anything one can do to improve readability in markup is a win, but functionally, classes work just as well.

Comment: 1) `data-` is safer since there is no possibility of a collision with a real class (this is a plus). 2) using `data-` I would imagine be faster (no need to parse). 3) CSS-tools (editor, refactoring, etc.) might get in a way.

Comment: @user93422 - good points also. Your point #1 is part of why I don't like using classes, it's confusing and potentially risky.

Answer (score 5):

You chould use "#update" or "#insert" but instead, you should use the class attribute to differentiate them. Can you have multiple classes for a single element and unlike the ID attribute, it's okay to have several of the same classes all over your document.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="update_buton submit_button">Update</a>
```

You'll then be able to do this instead:

```
$('.update_button').click(function(e)
{
  // Do something here
});
```

If you need to be able to differentiate which type of "submit_button" was clicked, you could do this:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(e)
{
  // Common code up here

  if ( $(this).hasClass('.update_button') )
  {
    // Update here
  }
  else if ( $(this).hasClass('.other_button') )
  {
    // Other action here
  }

  // More common code down here
});
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I had nearly finished writing!

Comment: +1 for `pointing javascript:void(0);` - is that SEO friendly?

Comment: though I would recommend using jQuery metadata plugin to specify an operation (assuming that operation just needs to be included in the POST, and otherwise all operations are handled same way).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `href` attribute if the anchor is not pointing to an actual resource.

Use the `id` attribute to identify the oparation:

```
<a id="delete-017" class="delete-button">Item No. 17</a>
```

Btw, this is how Stack Overflow is doing it... (the "link", "flag", "delete", "edit" buttons)

Comment: this approach is a little more complicated than usind `data-`, I wonder why SO does it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be penalized for using href="#" or href="#update" aka blind links.

My understanding of SEO is that a crawler will crawl a resource or it wont.  It then calculates the relativity of the crawled / cached content with the search keywords.

How much searchable content will you really have on pages that are forms?  Would you even want crawlers to index that content?  I would say that you probably dont have much searchable content on forms and you probably dont want crawling those pages anyway.

Regarding how to markup your code so that you can find it with jquery, I beleive that Francois Deschenes has the best answer.

Use css for jquery hooks, use href for what it is... a pointer to a resource.